# I want to search specific observations in a data frame and record them in an empty matrix. But, the code in not working.

Tags: r

```
search <- function(x,max_hp){
  count <- 1
  result <- matrix(NA, nrow =nrow(x), ncol = ncol(x), byrow = TRUE)
  for(i in 1:nrow(x)){
    temp_row <- x[i,]
    if(temp_row[4] < max_hp){
      result[count,] <- temp_row
      count <- count + 1
    }
  }
  return(result)
}

> search(mtcars,240)
Error in result[count, ] <- temp_row : 
  incorrect number of subscripts on matrix
```

#I want the search function to return all observations in mtcars that      #have an horsepower less than 240 and record it in a new matrix.

Answer (score 0):

To return a dataframe the same size as mtcars filled with NA,

```
newmt <- mtcars
newmt[newmt$hp>=240, ]  <-  NA
```

If you really need a matrix, use `as.matrix` on the result.